# Eigenvectors of large low-rank plus random asymmetric square matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Suppose I have a large $N$-by-$N$ random, asymmetric, square matrix, $X$ (e.g. Gaussian i.i.d. elements with variance $\frac{1}{N}$). And I add a low-rank matrix, say for simplicity, rank one, $\lambda u v^T$:
$$ J=\lambda u v^T +X$$

Suppose for example, that $\lambda$ is sufficiently large that there is an outlier eigenvalue in $J$. What is the overlap of the associated eigenvector of $J$ with $u$ and $v$?

I know the answer for the symmetric (Hermitian) case, following [Baik-Ben Arous-Peche](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403022), and presented for example in Potters and Bouchaud A First Course in Random Matrix Theory Ch 14. I also know the relationship between the **singular vectors** of $J$ and $u$/$v$, following results by [Benayach-Georges and Nadakuditi 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2221). Are there analogous results for the eigenvectors of non-Hermitian matrices?

Comment: In your question statement, what is $X$? Is $X$ the random asymmetric square matrix? If so, I think your first sentence should change $J$ to $X$, yes?

Comment: You're right! Thanks Rylan!